# Dante authenticating user

Tags: proxy, authentication, socks

I have this VPS that has 5 external/public ip addresses and, on only one of them I want to allow user 'someuser' to login in dante:

```
internal: 122.231.9.3 port = 1080

external: 122.231.9.3

socksmethod: username none
clientmethod: none

user.privileged: root
user.notprivileged: nobody

external.rotation: same-same

client pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: error connect disconnect
}

socks pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 122.231.9.3/32
        user: someuser
        socksmethod: username
        log: error connect disconnect
}
```

If I remove the `122.231.9.3/32` bit and replace it with `0.0.0.0/0` the authentication works fine but not this way.

I'm basically trying to create 4 users, each able to authenticate to a different public ip.

Answer (score 0):

You can just run 4 dante instances every of them with a difeerent configuration file , and just put a different ip and port to listen to , in every configuration.
Just modify the lines

```
internal: 122.231.9.3 port = 1080

external: 122.231.9.3
```

to be different for every configuration file , so every dante instance to use a different configuration file ,that has a different ip and port to listen for

Comment: Sorry, but that's not a solution for me. I said 4 just to keep it simple. It may be a /22 class.